# Scale figure's font with seaborn while preserving matplotlib's style

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have some predefined `matplotlibrc` style which I use for my plots. Below is a sample image styled with it

[image]

On the other hand, I find seaborn's `sns.set(font_scale=1.25)` quite handy, which allows me to quickly control font sizes.
Yet, while changing the font size it also applies the **default seaborn style** to my plot, so matplotlib's defaults are overwritten.
I tried `sns.set(style=None, font_scale=1.25)` instead but line colors and font family of axis labels are still changed.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

#sns.set(style=None, font_scale=1.25)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3.4, 2.1), frameon=False)
fig.tight_layout()

x = np.linspace(0, 2, 500)

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_xlabel('xlabel, some units')
ax.set_ylabel('ylabel, some units')

ax.plot(x, x**0.5, label='$x^{0.5}$')
ax.plot(x, x**1.5, label='$x^{1.5}$')
ax.legend()

fig.savefig('output.png')
plt.close(fig)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to rite your own function that reproduces what seaborn is doing "under the hood"

This is adapted from [seaborn's code on github](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/c0a6d850d29b7b8c0e3ecc8a14c76f11880fb9f9/seaborn/rcmod.py#L420):

```
def scale_fonts(font_scale):
    font_keys = ["axes.labelsize", "axes.titlesize", "legend.fontsize",
             "xtick.labelsize", "ytick.labelsize", "font.size"]
    font_dict = {k: matplotlib.rcParams[k] * font_scale for k in font_keys}
    matplotlib.rcParams.update(font_dict)
```

You have to make sure the values for the `font_keys` above are in numeric (e.g. 12 and not "medium") in your rc-file, but otherwise, that's all there is to it.

Comment: Thanks! I just started considering setting `font_keys` (except `font.size`) with non-numeric values, so changing `font.size` in `rcParams` will affect `font_keys`.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for [`set_context`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.set_context.html#seaborn.set_context):

```
sns.set_context("notebook", font_scale=1.25)
```

This will scale the fonts with respect to the predefined `"notebook"` style, which seems closest to the matplotlib defaults.

A comparisson:

Default plot:

[image]

With `sns.set_context(font_scale=1.25)`:

[image]

With `sns.set_context("notebook", font_scale=1.25)`:

[image]

Comment: Well, it looks `context="notebook"` is the default of `sns.set`, so it doesn't change the style.

Comment: Yep exactly, as I understood you do not want to change the style, just the font sizes.

Comment: I mean setting "notebook" context is the same as `sns.set(font_scale=1.25)`, and it does change a few things.

Comment: It looks, for the second plot `context=None` (I was getting similar output for this setting). What is your seaborn version?

Comment: I have the newest seaborn version (0.8.1) installed.

Comment: The closest working thing I got is `sns.set(style=None, font_scale=1.0, font='sans', palette=None)`. It does preserve the font family (forced to) and doesn't change colors.

Comment: Works like a charm for me. Was having the problem too that all colors were changed. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This is a good answer, seems simpler than Diziet Asahi's and it works. However, as -taras points out setting "notebook" will change the parameters set by the context and can be called by using sns.plotting_context.
https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.set_context.html